# URL re-writing rule to make url case insensitive

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get the following URLs be case insensitive and to go to same spot:

http://www.mywebsite.com/test

http://www.mywebsite.com/TEST

I have the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/?$ /?param=$1 [L]
```

It works for lowercase but when I have 'TEST' after website name, it doesn't apply.

I get `The requested URL /TEST.php was not found on this server`.  Appending .php is another URL rule that comes after the rule above. So it looks like, it doesn't match the rule and goes on to next.

Comment: does the RewriteRule not apply or your [asp|php|...) script?

Comment: I get The requested URL /TEST.php was not found on this server. Appending .php is another URL rule that comes after the rule above. So it looks like it doesn't match the rule and goes on to next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try the following:**

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)?$ /index.php?param=$1 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/?$ /index.php?param=$1
```

Explicitly referring to the index file makes it clearer. The second rule should be added if you want to match trailing slashes on your 'test' param.

This works with both `http://www.mywebsite.com/test` and `http://www.mywebsite.com/TEST`